# Number of induced subgraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have the following two properties and do not understand, why they are equivalent:

\begin{equation}
N_{G}^{*}(H(s))=(1+o(1))n^s2^{-\binom{s}{2}},
\end{equation}
where $N_{G}^{*}(H(s))$ is the number of labeld occurrences of $H$ as an induced subgraph of $G$. 
\begin{equation}
N_{G}^{*}(H(s))=(1+o(1))n_{(s)}2^{-\binom{s}{2}},\end{equation} 
where $n_{(s)}=n(n-1)\cdots(n-s+1)$.

Comment: asymptotically $n_{(s)}=n^s$

Comment: Thank you @Countingstuff ! Is this equivalent: $n^{s}s^{-\binom{s}{2}}+o(n^s)=n_{(s)}s^{-\binom{s}{2}}+o(n^s)$.? I cannot see it..

Comment: I'll grant you that I've never been particularly happy with all this notation either, but to make things clear let's say we have $c_n\rightarrow 0$ such that the expression they are interested in equals $(1+c_n)n_{(s)}2^{-{{s}\choose{2}}}$. There is $w_n\rightarrow 1$ such that $n_{(s)}=w_n n^s$, hence their expression is $(1+(w_n-1+w_nc_n))n^s2^{-{{s}\choose{2}}}$ which is $(1+o(1))n^s2^{-{{s}\choose{2}}}$

Comment: Thank you very much! The notations are quite confusing, but your solution makes sense.